# Android: Detect position of another phone relative to your phone

Tags: android

An unusual question, but just something that randomly popped into my head.

Wondering if anybody had given this some thought with the current day technology.
It'd might be a pretty neat feature for a multiplayer game.

I know NFC's can detect another device in a nearby proximity, but does it have the ability to detect what angle the device is?

I'm talking about nearby positioning, like within bluetooth or wifi connectivity range.
Nothing related to using GPS or the internet.

Comment: Nothing would stop you from transmitting the phone's orientation via bluetooth or wifi or whatever to the other phone. Not sure if that will give you enough information to compute their relative positioning though... actually I think my android is some kind of built in compass too...so knowing their orientation relative to the north pole, and using all the other accelerometers and gyroscopes, you should be able to get a pretty good idea...except for distance from each other, I think.

Comment: Ah yes that's a very good point Mark, I completely forgot about the compass feature! Yeah, the distance bit is a bit of a tricky one too.

First thing that comes to mind may be the use of bluetooth ping timing to measure the distance. Might not be possible though.

Answer (score 0):

No, NFC is for two devices in close proximity to each other, usually by no more than a few centimeters, (almost touching each other). It can't be used in  multiplayer games unless it involves bumping the two phones together